# Does Time division duplexing work this way?

Tags: duplex, half-duplex

During the course of research, I have found a really hard time understanding this short lines below. I will appreciate a short hint or explanation from any expert in this area.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3):

Time division duplex (TDD) concerns at least a 2 way communication. For example, a discussion is taking place between two people, say a and b, a talks whilst b listens, then b talks whilst a listens. A and b can't talk at the same time, hence timely divided and both share a time unit. Full duplex can be imagined as if both a and b talk and listen at the same time which double the amount of the information exchanged. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you so much for your kind response. when we use 50 devices based on TDD, and we have a maximum of 30 relays (for example), 25 of those devices can be transmitting to relays while the relays also transmit to another 25? i.e The relay receives 'input' 25 in a time slot while it sends another 25 in the different time slot?

Comment: So for instance based on the modified diagram above, the relays can receive a total of $\lambda_1P_{re}$ which is shared into two halves (for reception and transmission)?